# My page behind code created button onclick function isnt working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created button manually from the behind code page using asp.net WebForms.
That is the creation code:

```
                    Button myButton = new Button();
                    myButton.ID = "b" + arrcodes[i];
                    myButton.Text = "Buy Now!";
                    myButton.CssClass = "btn-primary";     
                    myButton.Click +=  new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
                    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myButton);
```

I googled how to add onClick function and used method which founded here in stackoverflow. But this method not working.. the function "myButton_Click" isnt activated when i press the button.

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { // my code }
```

Have i did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reload that dynamically created button on postback with same Id inside `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` event.

Otherwise, it won't be in the Control Tree, and cannot trigger the Click event.

*For example,*

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init()
    {
        CreateButton();
    }

    protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void CreateButton()
    {
        Button myButton = new Button();
        myButton.ID = "b1";
        myButton.Text = "Buy Now!";
        myButton.CssClass = "btn-primary";
        myButton.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
        myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myButton);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the better option is to create the button and toggle it's visibility.

If you really need to create it dynamically, make sure you're creating the button in OnInit method for event handler to work.

Comment: This should be a comment.